# Length of words in a list without counting punctuation symbols

Tags: python

I have written below code to find length of words taking input ignoring some special characters in Python

```
def word_length_list(text):
    special_characters = ["'","?"]
    for string in special_characters:
        clean_text = text.replace(string, "")
    count_list = [len(i) for i in clean_text.split()]
    print count_list
```

The output is accepting only the first special character and ignoring the rest. 
Please suggest what is wrong with my code here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing multiple replaces, you need to update the same variable (`clean_text`) with each replace:

```
def word_length_list(text):
    special_characters = ["'","?"]
    clean_text = text
    for string in special_characters:
        clean_text = clean_text.replace(string, "")
    count_list = [len(i) for i in clean_text.split()]
    print count_list
```

This way multiple special characters will be removed:

```
>>> word_length_list("abc def ' ghi ? lmo")
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Bejado